# How is it ensured that a user is not reading stale(not yet synced) data from read only Redis slave?

Tags: caching, redis, distributed-system

I am learning about Redis replication and I understood following facts

```
1. By Default replicas are read only.
2. All writes happen to master
3. Master writes changes to internal buffer and then sends them slave for sync
4. Slave receives the buffered information and writes them to their memory
```

I have a doubt/curiosity here -

Let us assume
master has a `key:value` as `name:rishi`.
this key-value is also in-sync/replicated in slave.

Now user updates the key name with a new value `name:coder`, and master puts the data in internal buffer to make it sync with slave/s.

Then, before slaves are updated a read query comes to Redis for "name" key, is there a chance that stale data can be read out of salves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a small time window where older data can be read from replica (fka slave) nodes.

Reference: [Redis Replication](https://redis.io/topics/replication)

Comment: is there a way to avoid it? can we amend redis.conf to only acknowledge a write once data is synced with slaves. (I am doubtful as communication with salves is async)

Comment: also is there a documentation available with states the same?

Comment: @Rishi link added in answer

Answer (score 0):

I think *replica-serve-stale-data* is useful in this situation. Based on [this config files](https://redis.io/docs/management/config-file/) and its comments, *replica-serve-stale-data no* on all replicas (slaves) and the master. This helps to maintain consistency across your Redis deployment and ensures that clients always receive up-to-date information.:

> When a replica loses its connection with the master, or when the
> replication  is still in progress, the replica can act in two
> different ways:
>
> 1. if replica-serve-stale-data is set to 'yes' (the default) the
>    replica will
>    still reply to client requests, possibly with out of date data, or the
>    data set may just be empty if this is the first synchronization.
> 2. If replica-serve-stale-data is set to 'no' the replica will reply
>    with error
>    "MASTERDOWN Link with MASTER is down and replica-serve-stale-data is set to 'no'"
>    to all data access commands, excluding commands such as:
>    INFO, REPLICAOF, AUTH, SHUTDOWN, REPLCONF, ROLE, CONFIG, SUBSCRIBE,
>    UNSUBSCRIBE, PSUBSCRIBE, PUNSUBSCRIBE, PUBLISH, PUBSUB, COMMAND, POST,
>    HOST and LATENCY.
>
> replica-serve-stale-data yes

By configuring all instances (master and slaves) with replica-serve-stale-data no, you prioritize consistency over serving potentially outdated data. This can be important in scenarios where maintaining data integrity and consistency is crucial, even if it means that replicas might experience temporary unavailability when they fall behind.